# What is the necklace that the Wicked Witch/Zelenia wears?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In Once Upon a Time I noticed that both the Wicked Witch and her counterpart self Zelina in Storybrooke both wear a emerald green necklace? What is it? Is it the source of her magic or is it just for decoration?

[image]

Heres the image for those who don't know what I mean. Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: We haven't been told. On the plus side, mysteries in *Once Upon a Time* usually only take a few episodes to be unravelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necklace could be just there to go with her green skin and the green smoke but it could possibly have an charm like the silver whistle the witch had in the book that summoned wolves, crows, and black bees. Maybe later in the show it could be reveled.

It has been reveled that if taken from her she could loes control of her power. Also Glinda has one with a white gem.

Answer (score 0):

[spoilers] Yes, the pendant does protect and grow Zelina's magic, but the reason she wears it when the town is cursed (for the second time) is because she was the one that cast the spell and she knows what can happen and she won't just leave her magic behind because if she does not wear it, she is powerless